# How to describe this syntax logically?

Tags: c#, console-application

I don't understand how the code works.

Why does the code output "5"?

Here's the code:

```
        int x = 55;
        int y = 5;

        switch (x % 8)
        {
            case 0: case 1:
                y++;
                break;
            case 2:case 3:
                y = y + 2;
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                y = y - 3;
                break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(+y);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Because the value of `y` is never changed. Because `55 % 8 == 7` and your `switch` statement does not handle that case nor does it handle [the `default` case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#the-default-case). Also, why do you think you need a `switch` case if the value of `x` is known beforehand?

Comment: Why do _you_ think it _shouldn't_ be "5"?

Comment: Do note the same would happen if the modulus happened to be 4.

Comment: Your best option for questions like these is to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
55 % 8 = 7
```

Your `switch` statement does not have `case 7:` so you did not change the value of your `y` variable and print out `5`

You can refer more at [remainder-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-)

Comment: what problem? he assign x = 55?

Comment: `x % 8 == 55 % 8 == 7`, is that better?

Comment: Maybe the poster doesn't know what the modulo operator does: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: @RonaldKorze If that was the case, and OP wanted to do `55 / 7` his `case 0:` makes no sense

Comment: @bradbury9 this is assignment from my teacher to me explain the logic, no wonder it makes no sense